# how to present the data with "<" in a PLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a line + point plot. But my data contain "<" Is it possible to make the special point  for the point with "<"? Any suggestion on how to better present those info?

[image]

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(Day = c(1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 15), Score = c("0.1", 
"0.5", "<1.3", "0.2", "<1.55", "0.8", "1.2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my plot code and sample:

```
df<- df %>%
  mutate(Score1=gsub("<", "", Score))

ggplot(data=df26, aes(x=Day,y=Score1, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I think your data is very unusual. It is quite difficult to understand why you got "<1.55" and "<1.3", in some measurements, while you got "0.2" and "0.8" in others. Most plotting possibilities will not make this any clearer, not so sure why you would like to make a plot here

Comment: They are test results. Different labs report it in different way. So I am think to plot the input with "<" differently, so people can tell.

Comment: You may plot the "<" containing values without the "<", as numeric-only, than mark them with an asterisk using geom_text().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTW, your Score1 is still in `character` type, so it is not plotting proportional to its value. Here's one approach to use the value without "<" but the label including the "<".

There are lots of options here. A few below:

1. add the "<" to the axis labels
2. add a visual indicator (could be color, text, an arrow, etc.) to note "smaller than" values.
3. Color differently and use a legend. I like `ggtext` for this as you can use markup to color in specific words, which is great for incorporating color legends into explanatory text.
4. Perhaps "<1.3" could be interpreted, based on situational knowledge, that the measurement was somewhere below 1.3 but not below 1.2. Then we could show simulated possibilities.

---

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Day,y=as.numeric(Score1), group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(df$Score1), labels = df$Score, 
                     minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Or you might indicate visually that the values are smaller, esp. if there's some plausible range that they might be lower.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Day,y=as.numeric(Score1), group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = . %>% filter(Score1 != Score),
               aes(xend = Day, yend = as.numeric(Score1) - 0.2), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")), color = "gray60") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(df$Score1), labels = df$Score, minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

```
library(ggtext)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Day, y=as.numeric(Score1), group = 1,
                    shape = Score1 == Score)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(color = Score1 == Score)) +
  scale_shape_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"), guide = FALSE) +
  labs(caption = "<span style = 'color:#FF0000'>Red dots</span> were recorded with a '<'") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Another idea is we might show possibilities that are consistent with the measurement based on our situational understanding of what "<1.3" means -- ie maybe it means the value was "somewhere between 1.2 and 1.3."

```
df_possibilities <- df %>%
  filter(Score1 != Score) %>%
  uncount(10) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(adjusted = as.numeric(Score1) - runif(1, max = 0.1))


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Day,y=as.numeric(Score1), group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(df$Score1), labels = df$Score, 
                     minor_breaks = NULL) +
  geom_point(data = df_possibilities,
             aes(y = adjusted), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to change the dot type for those with "<" and then put it as legend or footnote? Change y-axis break works for sigle line. If I have multiple lines, then it might be the problem.

Comment: Adding arrow is a very unique way. :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of alternatives, inclulded in the same graph:

1. by  a key using a coloured `geom_point`, or
2. by annotation with `geom_text`

This is just to give an impression, both methods can be enhanced and modified to provide the appearance you think provides the best visualisation.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- 
  df%>% 
  mutate(y = as.numeric(str_extract(Score, "\\d.\\d{1,2}")),
         less_than = if_else(str_detect(Score, "<"), TRUE, FALSE))

ggplot(df1, aes(Day, y))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = less_than))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_text(aes(label = Score), hjust = -0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Labels idea from Peter. Thanks.
You can use `shape` for different shapes.
with `ggpubr` more sophisticated. Here a overview of the numbers:

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(Day),y=Score1, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=df[c(3,5),], aes(x=factor(Day), y=Score1), colour="red", size=5, shape=25) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Score), hjust = -0.2)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]